# bounding polygon of a sprite from pixi to p2

Tags: javascript, html, pixi.js

I am importing a sprite into PIXI using

```
var texture= PIXI.Texture.fromImage("img.png");
var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
// I set the position
stage.addChild(sprite);
```

I want to detect collisions on this sprite and since PIXI has no collision detection support. I am using [`p2.js`](https://schteppe.github.io/p2.js/) and this needs a polygon bounding box for collision detection

How can I get the polygon from pixi and pass it to p2 and detect a collision?

Any sample or some pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you want physics too? Or just get notified about overlaps?

Comment: @schteppe overlaps only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p2.js and Pixi.js have different coordinate systems, which makes the solution a bit complex. The "up" direction in p2.js is along the positive Y axis and in Pixi it's along negative Y. To get around this, one solution is to apply a negative scale to the Pixi stage to flip it upside down:

```
stage.scale.y = -1;
```

You need to add a p2.Body for each sprite. To transfer position and rotation data from Pixi.js sprites to p2.js bodies, do this:

```
body.position[0] = sprite.position.x;
body.position[1] = sprite.position.y;
body.angle = sprite.rotation;
```

To track overlaps you need to add contact listeners:

```
world.on('beginContact', function(evt){
    // evt.bodyA and evt.bodyB started overlapping!
});

world.on('endContact', function(evt){
    // evt.bodyA and evt.bodyB are not overlapping any more.
});
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/18shpxq8/2/